# Convert string to int in jquery and delete comma in string

Tags: jquery

I have code, I use it in jquery

```
var string = "123,123";
$.trim(",");
```

Let I show it in source code:

```
function calculate_total_money() {
sum_money = 0;
$('table#table_product tr.data td#total_money').each(function() {
    var _total_money = $(this).html();
    if (_total_money != '') {
        var total_money = _total_money;
        sum_money += total_money;
    }
});

$('table#table_product td#sum_total_money').html(formatNumber2(sum_money));}
```

This function return total money, but value of _total_money I get in table like that "23,123", but I want to convert it to Int 23123. I don't know how to do.

I want to delete comma in string, but it doesn't work. After delete comma, string must convert to Interger. I try many times but don't have anything happen. where's place I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var string = "123,123";
var str = parseInt(string.replace(",",""));
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5pbeu44v/1/)**

Answer (score 3):

If you have single `,` inside string use `replace`:

```
string = parseInt(string.replace(',', ''), 10);
```

**NOTE**: `replace` will only replace the first occurrence of `,`.

If you have **multiple `,`** inside string use `regex` in `replace`:

```
string = parseInt(string.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
```

`parseInt` to convert `string` to `integer`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ukw0vxgt/)

Answer (score 0):

trim only removes characters from beginning or end of string, not the middle.

use `replace` instead.

Comment: Thanh you very much !

Answer (score 0):

use `replace()` in javascript to remove the `,` then you have to convert string into number using `+ operator` or `parseInt()`

```
    var string = "123,123";
    string=+string.replace(",",""); //+ is used for convert string into number or use parseInt()
   // alert(string)
    //alert(typeof string  )
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5pbeu44v/)**

Comment: Thanh you very much !

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
var string = "123,123";
var val1 = parseInt(string.split(',')[0]);
var val2 = parseInt(string.split(',')[1]);
```

Comment: Thanh you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `String.prototype.match` , `RegExp` `/\d+/g/` , `Array.prototype.join()`

```js
var string = "123,123", n = Number(string.match(/\d+/g).join("")); console.log(n)
```

Comment: Thanh you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var string = "123,123";

parseInt(string.replace(",", ""));
```

Comment: Thanh you very much !